# how to enable all inputs before disable others with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

With function laisviLaikai() I'm trying to disable check input when I choose a date, and it works fine, but when I change date these inputs are still disabled.

So I write a code to handle that. When function is called the code have to enable all check inputs, but it not working.

This is Html my code:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    <input type="button" value="tikrinti" onclick="laisviLaikai()">

    <div class="radio">
        <h2>Pasirinkite laiką</h2><br>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="10-00">
        <label for="10-00"><span class="select" id="10-00-2">10:00</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="10-15">
        <label for="10-15"><span class="select" id="10-15-2">10:15</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="10-30">
        <label for="10-30"><span class="select" id="10-30-2">10:30</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="10-45">
        <label for="10-45"><span class="select" id="10-45-2">10:45</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="11-00">
        <label for="11-00"><span class="select" id="11-00-2">11:00</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="11-15">
        <label for="11-15"><span class="select" id="11-15-2">11:15</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="11-30">
        <label for="11-30"><span class="select" id="11-30-2">11:30</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="11-45">
        <label for="11-45"><span class="select" id="11-45-2">11:45</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="12-00">
        <label for="12-00"><span class="select" id="12-00-2">12:00</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="12-15">
        <label for="12-15"><span class="select" id="12-15-2">12:15</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="12-30">
        <label for="12-30"><span class="select" id="12-30-2">12:30</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="12-45">
        <label for="12-45"><span class="select" id="12-45-2">12:45</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="13-00">
        <label for="13-00"><span class="select" id="13-00-2">13:00</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="13-15">
        <label for="13-15"><span class="select" id="13-15-2">13:15</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="13-30">
        <label for="13-30"><span class="select" id="13-30-2">13:30</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="13-45">
        <label for="13-45"><span class="select" id="13-45-2">13:45</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="14-00">
        <label for="14-00"><span class="select" id="14-00-2">14:00</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="14-15">
        <label for="14-15"><span class="select" id="14-15-2">14:15</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="14-30">
        <label for="14-30"><span class="select" id="14-30-2">14:30</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="14-45">
        <label for="14-45"><span class="select" id="14-45-2">14:45</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="15-00">
        <label for="15-00"><span class="select" id="15-00-2">15:00</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="15-15">
        <label for="15-15"><span class="select" id="15-15-2">15:15</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="15-30">
        <label for="15-30"><span class="select" id="15-30-2">15:30</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="15-45">
        <label for="15-45"><span class="select" id="15-45-2">15:45</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="16-00">
        <label for="16-00"><span class="select" id="16-00-2">16:00</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="16-15">
        <label for="16-15"><span class="select" id="16-15-2">16:15</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="16-30">
        <label for="16-30"><span class="select" id="16-30-2">16:30</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="16-45">
        <label for="16-45"><span class="select" id="16-45-2">16:45</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="17-00">
        <label for="17-00"><span class="select" id="17-00-2">17:00</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="17-15">
        <label for="17-15"><span class="select" id="17-15-2">17:15</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="17-30">
        <label for="17-30"><span class="select" id="17-30-2">17:30</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="17-45">
        <label for="17-45"><span class="select" id="17-45-2">17:45</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="18-00">
        <label for="18-00"><span class="select" id="18-00-2">18:00</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="18-15">
        <label for="18-15"><span class="select" id="18-15-2">18:15</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="18-30">
        <label for="18-30"><span class="select" id="18-30-2">18:30</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="18-45">
        <label for="18-45"><span class="select" id="18-45-2">18:45</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="19-00">
        <label for="19-00"><span class="select" id="19-00-2">19:00</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="19-15">
        <label for="19-15"><span class="select" id="19-15-2">19:15</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="19-30">
        <label for="19-30"><span class="select" id="19-30-2">19:30</span></label>
        <input type="radio" name="pas-laikas" id="19-45">
        <label for="19-45"><span class="select" d="19-45-2">19:45</span></label>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Registruotis" onclick="getData()">
</form>
```

And this is my javascript function code:

```
function laisviLaikai() {
let tikrinamaData = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
console.log("Gaunama data is lauko " + tikrinamaData);



//Pasalina pazymetus laikus jei buvo pazymeti
let pazLaik = document.getElementsByName("pas-laikas");
for (let b = 0; b < pazLaik.length; b++) {
    pazLaik[b].disabled = false;
}

let db;
let request = window.indexedDB.open("InfoDB", 1);

request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Klaida: " + e.target.error);
};

request.onsuccess = function (e) {
    db = e.target.result;
    let tran = db.transaction(["info"], "readwrite");
    let objektas = tran.objectStore("info");
    let ats = objektas.getAll();

    ats.onsuccess = function(){
        let atsakymas = ats.result;
        for (let a = 0; a < atsakymas.length; a++){
            if (tikrinamaData === atsakymas[a].data){
                let banLaikas = atsakymas[a].laikas;
                let blLaikas = document.getElementById(banLaikas);
                blLaikas.disabled = true;
                let inactive = document.getElementById(banLaikas+"-2");
                inactive.style = "background: #969696;";
                console.log("loop " + atsakymas[a].data)
           }
        }

    }

    tran.oncomplete = function(e) {
       console.log("baigta");
  };
}

}
```

And code in function which have to make check inputs not disabled:

```
let pazLaik = document.getElementsByName("pas-laikas");
for (let b = 0; b < pazLaik.length; b++) {
    pazLaik[b].disabled = false;
}
```

So in result this function, when is called, have to make all check inputs with name "pas-laikas" enabled, and then disable when it meets requirement in other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to get the radios by class instead name

```
<input type="radio" class="pas-laikas" id="10-00">
```

In javascript:

```
let pazLaik = document.querySelectorAll(".pas-laikas");
```

Comment: That's the solution, and code finally works. Thank you Maikon!